# Sort non-comparable objects

Tags: java, sorting

I have a list of Objects which are not comparable. I however would still like to sort this list of Objects based on a provided array of index positions. What is the fastest and most efficient way to sort this list? Here is an example:

```
List<Colour> list = new ArrayList<Colour>();
list.add(Colour.BLUE);
list.add(Colour.GREEN);
list.add(Colour.RED);
list.add(Colour.YELLOW);
list.add(Colour.GREEN);

int[] order = new int[] {3, 1, 2, 0, 4};
```

The final list should look like:

```
[YELLOW, GREEN, RED, BLUE, GREEN]
```

My specific requirement is for a solution in Java but I would be interested to know the solution in other languages as well.

Comment: java.util.Comparator is your solution

Comment: You should use Map instead List

Comment: A Comparator is of no use. How do you define which should go first between RED and GREEN given the desired order requires them to in both orders? Please read the question fully.

Comment: A comparator could perfectly be used: get the index of the two colours in the list, get the index of each color index in the order array, and compare those order indices.

Comment: @Alex, sure you can use comparator, you need to pass `order` as parameter. Yet, if you have already the final indexes, the list is virtually sorted, i assumed you had only relative indexes (i.e. which defines the colour order), not the final ones. The question is just trivial w/ final indexes, so it didn't even cross my mind it could have been that.

Comment: @bestsss. Even if you pass the order array as a parameter to your Comparable I still don't see how you could use it to compare two Colour objects given that you won't know the position of the two objects being compared in the original list. Could you please provide an answer that works with Comparable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why don't you just create the list from the indexes directly? No "sorting" is required.

```
List<Colour> sortedList = new ArrayList<Colour>();
for (int index : order) {
    sortedList.add(list.get(index));
}
```

Or C#:

```
var sorted = order.Select(index => list[index]).ToList();
```

Comment: I love answers of the sort "the best way to do X is not to do it".